# Unit testing large non-member functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a function, which I'd like to get under test. However, it's very large and creates a finite state machine. The function looks roughly like:

```
std::auto_ptr<IFiniteStateMachine> CreateFSM() 
{
    std::auto_ptr<IFiniteStateMachine> = apFSM( new CFiniteStateMachine() );

    std::list<IState*> listStates;

    listState.push_back( new CStateFoo( /*params*/ ) );
    listState.push_back( new CStateBar( /*params*/ ) );

    // etc.

    apFSM->AddState( listStates );

    // Define the transition table
    // 1st param: event received
    // 2nd param: current state
    // 3rd param: next state
    apFSM->AddTransition( "EventA", "StateFoo", "StateBar" );

    // etc.

    return apFSM;
}
```

Basically, this function just creates a FSM, states, and transition tables. Each of the individual components (the IFiniteStateMachine and IState classes) are testable.

So my question is: can a function like this be put under test? I'm not sure how you would even verify that this function worked as expected. I could probably divide it up into smaller functions that create states and transitions. However, a function that just created these states also seems rather complicated and hard to test.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you write assertions based on the presence of states in transions in the resulting FSM?

Comment: Any way to use mock objects in C++?  Mock objects are usually helpful for testing things like this.

Comment: @Kaleb: that's true, but how would I use the Mock objects? In the test, I would have to call CreateFSM(). There's no way for me to use dependency injection.

Comment: @Steve: that's what I'm leaning towards. I suppose I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to test it (or maybe I'm just over thinking it).

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what should be true after the function has run? Sounds like in this case a certain state machine should be in place - so that's what you should check for so you can do something like:

```
FSM expectedFSM = Factory.blankFSM().addState().addTransition().... etc
FSM actualFSM = CreateFSM();
ASSERT(expectedFSM == actualFSM); //assuming such == exists
```

or sometimes an easier way of doing this could be using string represntation/serialization:

```
String expectedFSMStr = loadFSMFromFile(expectedOutput1);
FSM actualFSM = CreateFSM();
ASSERT_EQUALS(expectedFSMStr, actualFSM.toString());
```

This can be easier to debug and is very useful if your classes have a reliable toStrinb/serialization method.